# onclick event was supposed go to the IP address then logout but it only shows the IP of button pressed

Tags: javascript, jquery

the button was supposed to go to IP address of button pressed then also logout but it doesn't

I have made script that can logout after few minutes , but its not in the scope of the project

```html
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Title of the document</title>
</head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">

<body>
  <p>
    <button type="cape" id="cape " onclick="window.location.href = 'http://10.23.32.20();';'logout.php();'">Cape </button>
  </p>
  <button type="cape" id="cape" onclick="window.location.href = 'http://10.23.30.20();';'logout.php();'">Quay 4 </button>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: `'http://10.23.32.20();';'logout.php();'` - can you please explain this?

Comment: the button has a link of an ip address & logout file.php the user is supposed to click the button & then second function is supposed to logout autamatically & return to login page

Comment: okay, now can you please explain this - `'http://10.23.30.20();'`. When i exec your code snippet, i get this: `'Uncaught SyntaxError: Failed to set the 'href' property on 'Location': 'http://10.23.32.20();' is not a valid URL.'`

Comment: use directly onclick="location='http://10.23.30.20/'" to go to this ip adress and if you have a logout() function you add after ;  -----> onclick="location='http://10.23.30.20/';logout()"

Comment: its working when I execute when I run the snippet, on stack overflow I don't know if its the syntax or what, I have seen many examples showing multiple functions with alert "method" I just need the code to go to the IP address and logout , the IP & logout file are working just fine,

Answer (score -1):

```
function logout()
{
    // simply calling the logout.php page

      $.ajax({
        type: 'post',
        url: 'logout.php',
        data: $('form').serialize(),
        success: function () {

         // window.location.replace("http://10.23.30.20/");
             window.location.href = "http://10.23.30.20/"
        }
      });
}


 <button type="cape" id="cape " onclick="logout()">Cape </button>
```

Comment: You can't reliably make an Ajax request while navigating to a new page. Most of the time the Ajax request will be cancelled as the execution environment is destroyed.

Comment: in this case you need to call location='http://10.23.30.20/" after ajax post success @Quentin